# file.exists() returns different value for same file in different activity

Tags: android, kotlin

My app downloads PDF files. So in some activities I need to check which files are available to do some operation. I am using the below code to check if the file is available -

```
val file = File(getDir(book))

if (file.exists()) {
   // do some stuff
} else {
   // do other stuff
}
```

Here is the code for getDir function -

```
fun getDir(book: Book): String {
  return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + File.separator +
      "PDF FOLDER/${book.layer_name}/${book.class_name}/${book.name}.pdf"
}
```

This piece of code is working perfectly in **Activity 1** where the file is downloaded from. But When I go to **Activity 2** this method says the file does not exist.

I logged getDir(book) from both activities and they are 100% same. The logs are below -

```
E/loggg: /storage/emulated/0/PDF FOLDER/Primary/Class1/my_book.pdf
E/loggg: /storage/emulated/0/PDF FOLDER/Primary/Class1/my_book.pdf
```

And when I download files from Activity 2 the codes works perfectly again.

What could be the reason behind this problem? I can't see any problem in my code. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Possibly a permission issue?

Comment: I have taken runtime permission for storage and files are opening with the permission. So I can assure that it is not a permission issue.

Comment: When you open Activity2?

Comment: Activity 1 and Activity 2 are not connected.. Each activity is launched from main acrivity.

Comment: When you download file from activity1 then open activity2 and do nothing just check file explorer is there that file?

Comment: Activity 2 is Bookmark activity. When I bookmark file from activity 1 it appears in Activity 2. But if the file is downloaded from activity 1 and bookmarked it is not treated as downloaded in activity 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### **SOLUTION**

After a while I found the problem. Still don't know the exact reason.

After downloading the PDF I was opening another activity from
**Activity 1(from where the file is downloaded)** to read the PDF file **without finishing Activity 1**. Then when I went back to Activity 2(Bookmark activity) file.exist() was returning ***false***.

But if I **finish Activity 1** after downloading the file and head back to Activity 2 file.exist() is returning ***true***.

Answer (score 2):

For a job safe, try use a `interface` where this code is shared, this avoid duplicate codes and this diminishes the cases like this (where the same code block not work)

Try

```
open class ActivityBase: AppCompatActivity {
    protected fun getDir(book: Book): String {
        return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + File.separator + 
        "PDF FOLDER/${book.layer_name}/${book.class_name}/${book.name}.pdf"
    }
}

class Activity1: ActivityBase

class Activity2: ActivityBase
```

Maybe this above code be helpfull to you

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. But getDir function is in an Util class. So it is not repeating.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Zoe for you atention, but `interface` is just a term to this ;-)